# Specializing templates based on methods

Tags: c++, templates, generics, duck-typing

Recently I've been programming a lot in Java, now I'm coming back to my C++ roots (I really started missing the pointers and segmentation faults). Knowing that C++ has a broad support for templates I was wondering whether it has some capabilities of Java which could be useful for writing generalized code. Lets say I'have two groups of classes. One of them has the `first()` method, the other one has the `second()` method. Is there a way of specializing the templates to be picked by the compiler depending on the methods one class possesses? I'm aiming at behavior which is similar to the one of Java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        First first = () -> System.out.println("first");
        Second second = () -> System.out.println("second");
        method(first);
        method(second);
    }

    static <T extends First> void method(T argument) {
        argument.first();   
    }

    static <T extends Second> void method(T argument) {
        argument.second();
    }
}
```

Where `First` and `Second` are interfaces. I know I could group both of these groups by deriving each of them from an upper class, but it's not always possible (no autoboxing in C++ and some classes don't inherit from a common ancestor).

A good example of my needs is the STL library, where some classes have methods like `push()` and some others have  `insert()` or `push_back()`. Lets say I want to create an function which has to insert multiple values into an container using an variadic function. In Java it's easy to perform because collections have a common ancestor. In C++ on the other hand it's not always the case. I tried it by duck-typing, but the compiler yields an error message:

```
template <typename T>
void generic_fcn(T argument) {
    argument.first();
}

template <typename T>
void generic_fcn(T argument) {
    argument.second();
}
```

So my question is: Is implementing such behavior possible without creating  unnecessary boileplate code by specializing every single case?

Comment: You can use a policy class as another template parameter, and inherit from it. Then you have policy implementations for the different container types. See also [Policy Based Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design)

Comment: Could you show me an example how this could solve the problem? Because it sounds like it's worth a try.

Comment: There's a sample at the wikipedia article, and if you search for these words you'll find many more.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of `<T extends First>`, you will use something we call sfinae. This is a technique about adding constaints on a function based on parameter types.

Here's how you'd do it in c++:

```
template <typename T>
auto generic_fcn(T argument) -> void_t<decltype(argument.first())> {
    argument.first();
}

template <typename T>
auto generic_fcn(T argument) -> void_t<decltype(argument.second())> {
    argument.second();
}
```

For the function to exist, the compiler will need the type of `argument.second()` or the type of `argument.first()`. If the expression does not yield a type (ie. `T` has not a `first()` function), the compiler will try another overload.

`void_t` is implemented as follow:

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void;
```

Another great thing is that if you have such class:

```
struct Bummer {
    void first() {}
    void second() {}
};
```

Then the compiler will effectively tell you that the call is ambiguous because the type match both constraints.

---

If you really want to test if a type extends another (or implement, in c++ it's the same thing) you can use the type trait `std::is_base_of`

```
template <typename T>
auto generic_fcn(T argument) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<First, T>::value> {
    argument.first();
}

template <typename T>
auto generic_fcn(T argument) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Second, T>::value> {
    argument.second();
}
```

To read more about this topic, check [sfinae](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) on cpprefence, and you can check [available traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) provided by the standard library.

Answer (score 5):

so many options available in c++.

My preference is to favour free functions and return any result type correctly.

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
  int first() { return 1; }
};

struct Y
{
  double second() { return 2.2; }
};


//
// option 1 - specific overloads
//

decltype(auto) generic_function(X& x) { return x.first(); }
decltype(auto) generic_function(Y& y) { return y.second(); }

//
// option 2 - enable_if
//

namespace detail {
  template<class T> struct has_member_first
  {
    template<class U> static auto test(U*p) -> decltype(p->first(), void(), std::true_type());
    static auto test(...) -> decltype(std::false_type());
    using type = decltype(test(static_cast<T*>(nullptr)));
  };
}
template<class T> using has_member_first = typename detail::has_member_first<T>::type;

namespace detail {
  template<class T> struct has_member_second
  {
    template<class U> static auto test(U*p) -> decltype(p->second(), void(), std::true_type());
    static auto test(...) -> decltype(std::false_type());
    using type = decltype(test(static_cast<T*>(nullptr)));
  };
}
template<class T> using has_member_second = typename detail::has_member_second<T>::type;

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<has_member_first<T>::value>* =nullptr> 
decltype(auto) generic_func2(T& t)
{
  return t.first();
}

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<has_member_second<T>::value>* =nullptr> 
decltype(auto) generic_func2(T& t)
{
  return t.second();
}

//
// option 3 - SFNAE with simple decltype
//

template<class T>
auto generic_func3(T&t) -> decltype(t.first())
{
  return t.first();
}

template<class T>
auto generic_func3(T&t) -> decltype(t.second())
{
  return t.second();
}


int main()
{
  X x;
  Y y;

  std::cout << generic_function(x) << std::endl;
  std::cout << generic_function(y) << std::endl;

  std::cout << generic_func2(x) << std::endl;
  std::cout << generic_func2(y) << std::endl;

  std::cout << generic_func3(x) << std::endl;
  std::cout << generic_func3(y) << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can dispatch the call as it follows:

```
#include<utility>
#include<iostream>

struct S {
    template<typename T>
    auto func(int) -> decltype(std::declval<T>().first(), void())
    { std::cout << "first" << std::endl; }

    template<typename T>
    auto func(char) -> decltype(std::declval<T>().second(), void())
    { std::cout << "second" << std::endl; }

    template<typename T>
    auto func() { return func<T>(0); }
};

struct First {
    void first() {}
};

struct Second {
    void second() {}
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s.func<First>();
    s.func<Second>();
}
```

Method `first` is preferred over `second` if a class has both of them.
Otherwise, `func` uses function overloading to test the two methods and choose the right one.
This technique is called *sfinae*, use this name to search on the web for further details.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a little library that helps you determine if a member exists.

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class always_void, class...>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, std::void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply=details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>;
```

Now we can write has first and has second easily:

```
template<class T>
using first_result = decltype(std::declval<T>().first());
template<class T>
using has_first = can_apply<first_result, T>;
```

and similarly for `second`.

Now we have our method.  We want to call either first or second.

```
template<class T>
void method_second( T& t, std::true_type has_second ) {
  t.second();
}
template<class T>
void method_first( T& t, std::false_type has_first ) = delete; // error message
template<class T>
void method_first( T& t, std::true_type has_first ) {
  t.first();
}
template<class T>
void method_first( T& t, std::false_type has_first ) {
  method_second( t, has_second<T&>{} );
}
template<class T>
void method( T& t ) {
  method_first( t, has_first<T&>{} );
}
```

this is known as tag dispatching.

`method` calls the `method_first` which is determined if `T&` can be invoked with `.first()`.  If it can be, it calls the one that calls `.first().`

If it cannot, it calls the one that forwards to `method_second` and tests if it has `.second()`.

If it has neither, it calls an `=delete` function, which generates an error message at compile time.

There are many, many, many ways to do this.  I personally like tag dispatching because you can get better error messages out of failure to match than SFIANE generates.

In C++17 you can be more direct:

```
template<class T>
void method(T & t) {
  if constexpr (has_first<T&>{}) {
    t.first();
  }
  if constexpr (has_second<T&>{}) {
    t.second();
  }
}
```